# Check if textbox equals any value from data grid view column

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I want to check if the value of my textbox (`apTB`) at the time of a button press equals any value currently in a certain column (`column 0` (`alphapapa`)) in my data grid view (`apDGV`).

Current Code:

```
private void APButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (apTB.Text == apDGV.Columns[0])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate.", "Duplicate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
                stuff....
            }
```

But it is of course not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check every value in column, you must iterate through every row in column.
Additionally, it is good practice to write column names instead of numbers.

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
            if (textBox2.Text == row.Cells["columnName"].Value.ToString())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate.", "Duplicate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*apDGV.Columns[0]* is a DataGridViewColumn object.

To check the value of cells, adress them e.g. like this:

```
apDGV.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value
```

Just iterate with a loop over all the cells in your column and compare the values.